# Plantuml cant create PDF any longer

Tags: homebrew, plantuml

I was using plantuml to generate UML-class diagrams on my mac for a long time successfully. I installed plantuml with homebrew originally. Now suddenly I get the following error trying to generate a pdf file:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.pdf.PdfConverter.convert(PdfConverter.java:57)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.UmlDiagram.exportDiagramInternalPdf(UmlDiagram.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.UmlDiagram.exportDiagramNow(UmlDiagram.java:140)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.AbstractPSystem.exportDiagram(AbstractPSystem.java:157)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.PSystemUtils.exportDiagramsCuca(PSystemUtils.java:233)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.PSystemUtils.exportDiagrams(PSystemUtils.java:89)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.SourceFileReaderAbstract.getGeneratedImages(SourceFileReaderAbstract.java:160)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.manageFileInternal(Run.java:519)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.processArgs(Run.java:403)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.manageAllFiles(Run.java:370)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.main(Run.java:198)
```

Probably homebrew updated some packages and this causes some incompatibilities now. I already tried to uninstall and reinstall plantuml and all dependencies. Unfortunatley, without any success. I have the following package versions installed:

```
batik 1.14
fop 2.6
graphviz 2.47.2
librsvg 2.50.7
plantuml 1.2021.7
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this issue?

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: Did you solved the problem? Did you open an issue with homebrew?